# How do I rename a class including test target in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I frequently use Xcode refactor/rename tool to rename classes, variables, protocols, etc. in my code. It fails to rename the references to these classes in my tests target. How can I get the refactor/rename tool to rename these classes in both my regular target and my test target?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 13, renaming a function used in an application and test targets is only possible by renaming it from the test target.